# .net core 3 not having ReferenceLoopHandling in AddJsonOptions

Tags: json, asp.net-core

My csproject file is indicating: `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>`

In my startup im using the followinhg:

```
 services.AddMvc(x => x.Filters.AddService<TransactionFilter>())
        .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions... )
```

But, ReferenceLoopHandling  is not available inside `options.JsonSerializerOptions`.

[image]

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentNHibernate" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="FullContact.Contacts.API" Version="1.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.Storage.V1" Version="2.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="5.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="piplclient" Version="5.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="5.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

As part of the work to [improve the ASP.NET Core shared framework](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/a-first-look-at-changes-coming-in-asp-net-core-3-0/), [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) has been removed from the ASP.NET Core shared framework. Your app may require this reference if it uses Newtonsoft.Json-specific feature such as JsonPatch or converters or if it [formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.2) Newtonsoft.Json-specific types.

To use Json.NET in an ASP.NET Core 3.0 project:

Add a package reference to [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson).

Update `Startup.ConfigureServices` to call `AddNewtonsoftJson`.

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

This sets up MVC and configures it to use Json.NET instead of that new API. And that AddNewtonsoftJson method has an overload that allows you to configure the Json.NET options like you were used to with AddJsonOptions in ASP.NET Core 2.x.

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { … };
});
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666898/10201850

Comment: Second part should be:  
`services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);`

Comment: It is one way - to replace native .netcore 3.x serializer with Newton and use old way.
Question is why new serializer doesn't have circular reference ignore option.

By default they use JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth=0, which indicates max depth 64. And if you have loop in object graph it will crash -(((. 
Weird.
May be idea was not to return objects with loop, and produce output which "cleaned" (result of mapping from business entities).

Answer (score 33):

As of March 2020, the default JSON serializer does not support reference loop handling.

In order to handle that issue, you'll have to first install the older JSON serializer (used in older versions of .NET Core), `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` in the `Nuget` package manager.

The usage is pretty simple:

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(o => 
{
    o.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

Or like this if you are using a simple web API:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(o => 
{
    o.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

Comment: The question relates to supported features/behavior in the new System.Text.Json. Just "adding the old libraries" is not the answer sought for here.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned above you need to install **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson**, **Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Newtonsoft** packages and configure with **AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol** in order to still use Newtonsoft instead of System.Text.Json (ReferenceLoopHandling  not available yet)

For **SignalR** it would be

```
services.AddSignalR().AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol(p => 
{ 
    p.PayloadSerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
   version - 3.1.3
2. services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

Comment: Bless you! Here for being stuck in the Pluralsight course :)

Answer (score 1):

MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions

```
services.PostConfigure<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>(o => 
{
    o.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new MyCustomContractResolver()
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
    };

    o.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

Comment: Never come across this PostConfigure option before, but this was exactly what I needed - especially considering I'm no longer using `AddNewtonsoftJson` and I have **no clue** what is even registering `MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions`. I just can't find it anywhere, including source code.

Comment: @simon-weaver 
add Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson

Comment: what I meant was I couldn't find `services.Add<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>(...)` but it turns out it's because it's automatic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77161049/where-is-ioptionsmvcnewtonsoftjsonoptions-registered-in-asp-net-core-7