# How to create API endpoint to fetch Departments including Student in it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-webapi, endpoint

I have implemented a .net core web api with Student and Department entities. One to One relationship is implemented between these entities where departmentid is foreignkey for student table. How can I implement api end point in DepartmentController to fetch all the departments with student included in it?

**DepartmentController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Students.Models;

namespace Students.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DepartmentController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly StudentContext _context;

        public DepartmentController(StudentContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Department
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Department>>> GetDepartments()
        {
            return await _context.Departments.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Department/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Department>> GetDepartment(int id)
        {
            var department = await _context.Departments.FindAsync(id);

            if (department == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return department;
        }

        // PUT: api/Department/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutDepartment(int id, Department department)
        {
            if (id != department.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(department).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!DepartmentExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return Ok();
        }

        // POST: api/Department
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Department>> PostDepartment(Department department)
        {
            _context.Departments.Add(department);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetDepartment", new { id = department.Id }, department);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Department/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Department>> DeleteDepartment(int id)
        {
            var department = await _context.Departments.FindAsync(id);
            if (department == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Departments.Remove(department);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return department;
        }

        private bool DepartmentExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Departments.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

**Department.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Students.Models
{
    public class Department
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(20)")]
        public string Dep { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Student.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Students.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int SId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName ="varchar(50)")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**StudentContext.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Students.Models
{
    public class StudentContext:DbContext
    {
        public StudentContext(DbContextOptions<StudentContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**StudentController.cs**
**Please refer GetStudents()**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Students.Models;

namespace Students.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StudentsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly StudentContext _context;

        public StudentsController(StudentContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Students
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Student>>> GetStudents()
        {
            return await _context.Students.Include(d => d.Department).ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Students/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> GetStudent(int id)
        {
            var student = await _context.Students.Include(d => d.Department).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.SId == id);

            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return student;
        }

        // PUT: api/Students/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutStudent(int id, Student student)
        {
            if (id != student.SId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            _context.Departments.Update(student.Department);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            _context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!StudentExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return Ok();
        }

        // POST: api/Students
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> PostStudent(List<Student> student)
        {
            try
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < student.ToArray().Length; i++)
                {
                    _context.Students.Add(student[i]);
                }
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return CreatedAtAction("GetStudents", student);
            }
            catch
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            /*_context.Students.Add(student);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetStudent", new { id = student.SId }, student);*/
        }


        /*[HttpPost]
        [Route("StudentList")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> PostStudentList([FromBody] List<Student> student)
        {
            try
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < student.ToArray().Length; i++)
                {
                    _context.Students.Add(student[i]);
                }
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return CreatedAtAction("GetStudents", student);
            }
            catch
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }*/

        // DELETE: api/Students/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> DeleteStudent(int id)
        {
            var student = await _context.Students.FindAsync(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Students.Remove(student);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return student;
        }

        private bool StudentExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Students.Any(e => e.SId == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"One to One relationship"_ are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes. It is only for learning purpose.

Comment: I have already implemented this: `context.Students.Include(student => student.Department);` in StudentController but how to implement endpoint to fetch **Departments including Students in it**??

Comment: Can you update your example, so we can see, where you put it?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-3.0 use the include method on the student context to include the department like so:

```
context.Students.Include(student => student.Department);
```

It could be that you have to update your mapping so EF understands it. In that case, in your mapping you need to include a HasOne(student => student.Department) if necessary. or in your Department mapping, use a HasMany(department => department.Students) (but your department does not have a collection of students, so the latter would not be an option unless you change the model)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `Department` class to include the `Student` navigation property

```
public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
```

then in your `GetDepartments()` method, include the Student property

```
var query = _context.Departments.Include(d => d.Student);
```

that returns an IQueryable, so you can add another filtering

```
var filteredQuery = query.Where(d => d.Student.Name.Contains("jane"));
```

before you return it

```
return query.ToList();
```

or

```
return filteredQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: I have tried this. But it creates circular dependency between Student and Department

Comment: update your `Student` class to make it `virtual` for `Deparment` property
`public virtual Department Department { get; set; }`

Comment: Is there any other way possible using Include() and Where() so that I can iterate all the departments and can fetch student in it while GetDepartments()??

Comment: updated the answer, modify it to fit your needs. Mark it as answer if it resolved your issues. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried this. But it creates circular dependency between Student and Department

As above has said that you could add `Student` navigation property in `Department` model and use `Include` to retrieve data.

To prevent Reference Looping (or remove circular dependency between Student and Department here),you could use below code in startup `ConfigureServices`:

For asp.net core 2.2:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(
        options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);
```

For asp.net core 3.0:

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);
```

(You need to install the package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/3.0.0) firstly for 3.0)

Refer to [.net core 3 not having ReferenceLoopHandling in AddJsonOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58006152/net-core-3-not-having-referenceloophandling-in-addjsonoptions)