# GraphQL models struggling with System.Text.Json.JsonException

Tags: c#, graphql, graphql-dotnet

I created a new .NET Core project and installed the packages GraphQL, GraphiQL and GraphQL.SystemTextJson.

When running the application this is what I get

[image]

Besides the exception message GraphiQL wasn't able to find a schema documentation.

First of all I have two entities, users and tasks.

```
public sealed class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Task
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

and both of them have their representing graph type

```
public sealed class UserType : ObjectGraphType<User>
{
    public UserType()
    {
        Name = nameof(User);
        Field(user => user.Id).Description("The user id.");
    }
}

public sealed class TaskType : ObjectGraphType<Task>
{
    public TaskType()
    {
        Name = nameof(Task);
        Field(task => task.Id).Description("The task id.");
    }
}
```

I created the query holding all the "actions" the client can execute

```
public sealed class GraphQLQuery : ObjectGraphType
{
    private readonly List<User> _users = new List<User>();
    private readonly List<Task> _tasks = new List<Task>();

    public GraphQLQuery()
    {
        Field<ListGraphType<UserType>>(
            "users",
            "Returns a collection of users.",
            resolve: context => _users);

        Field<ListGraphType<TaskType>>(
            "tasks",
            "Returns a collection of tasks.",
            resolve: context => _tasks);
    }
}
```

and register that query for the schema

```
public sealed class GraphQLSchema : GraphQL.Types.Schema
{
    public GraphQLSchema(GraphQLQuery graphQLQuery, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(serviceProvider)
    {
        Query = graphQLQuery;
    }
}
```

In the startup file in the `ConfigureServices` I added this code to register all the required services before calling `services.AddControllers()`

```
serviceCollection
        .AddSingleton<IDocumentExecuter, DocumentExecuter>()
        .AddSingleton<IDocumentWriter, DocumentWriter>()
        .AddSingleton<ISchema, GraphQLSchema>()
        .AddSingleton<GraphQLQuery>()
```

and in the `Configure` method I call `app.UseGraphiQl()` at first.

The corresponding GraphQL request DTO

```
public sealed class GraphQLRequest
{
    public string OperationName { get; set; }
    public string Query { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectDictionaryConverter))]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Variables { get; set; }
}
```

Lastly I implemented the API controller

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public sealed class GraphQLController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISchema _schema;
    private readonly IDocumentExecuter _documentExecuter;

    public GraphQLController(ISchema schema, IDocumentExecuter documentExecuter)
    {
        _schema = schema;
        _documentExecuter = documentExecuter;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] GraphQLRequest graphQlRequest)
    {
        ExecutionOptions executionOptions = new ExecutionOptions()
        {
            Schema = _schema,
            Query = graphQlRequest.Query,
            Inputs = graphQlRequest.Variables?.ToInputs()
        };

        ExecutionResult executionResult = await _documentExecuter.ExecuteAsync(executionOptions);

        if (executionResult.Errors != null)
            return BadRequest(executionResult);

        return Ok(executionResult);
    }
}
```

Does someone know what's wrong here? I can't see problems like circular dependency etc.

---

When running the application the `graphQlRequest` contains the following values

- OperationName: IntrospectionQuery
- Query:

.

```
query IntrospectionQuery {
  __schema {
    queryType { name }
    mutationType { name }
    subscriptionType { name }
    types {
      ...FullType
    }
    directives {
      name
      description
      locations
      args {
        ...InputValue
      }
    }
  }
}

fragment FullType on __Type {
  kind
  name
  description
  fields(includeDeprecated: true) {
    name
    description
    args {
      ...InputValue
    }
    type {
      ...TypeRef
    }
    isDeprecated
    deprecationReason
  }
  inputFields {
    ...InputValue
  }
  interfaces {
    ...TypeRef
  }
  enumValues(includeDeprecated: true) {
    name
    description
    isDeprecated
    deprecationReason
  }
  possibleTypes {
    ...TypeRef
  }
}

fragment InputValue on __InputValue {
  name
  description
  type { ...TypeRef }
  defaultValue
}

fragment TypeRef on __Type {
  kind
  name
  ofType {
    kind
    name
    ofType {
      kind
      name
      ofType {
        kind
        name
        ofType {
          kind
          name
          ofType {
            kind
            name
            ofType {
              kind
              name
              ofType {
                kind
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

I migrated to .NET 5 now and get this error instead

[image]

---

I added a reproduction repository

https://github.com/olaf-svenson/graphql-net-reproduction

Comment: What's the value of `graphQlRequest`? you can add a json representation of its value to your question.

Comment: OfirD I added the value to my question :)

Comment: Can you upload full silution to Github? It will be easier to help if people can just clone and play with your repo

Comment: sure, give me a second

Comment: @Artur you can find it here https://github.com/olaf-svenson/graphql-net-reproduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error in .Net 5 related to unregistered graph types. If you enable all exceptions and disable "Just My Code" in debug settings you will see this error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Required service for type API.GraphTypes.UserType not found'
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    GraphQL.Utilities.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService(System.IServiceProvider, System.Type) in ServiceProviderExtensions.cs
    GraphQL.Types.Schema.CreateTypesLookup.AnonymousMethod__68_1(System.Type) in Schema.cs
    GraphQL.Types.GraphTypesLookup.Create.AnonymousMethod__0(System.Type) in GraphTypesLookup.cs
    GraphQL.Types.GraphTypesLookup.AddTypeIfNotRegistered(System.Type, GraphQL.Types.TypeCollectionContext) in GraphTypesLookup.cs
    GraphQL.Types.GraphTypesLookup.HandleField(GraphQL.Types.IComplexGraphType, GraphQL.Types.FieldType, GraphQL.Types.TypeCollectionContext, bool) in GraphTypesLookup.cs
    GraphQL.Types.GraphTypesLookup.AddType(GraphQL.Types.IGraphType, GraphQL.Types.TypeCollectionContext) in GraphTypesLookup.cs
    GraphQL.Types.GraphTypesLookup.Create(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<GraphQL.Types.IGraphType>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<GraphQL.Types.DirectiveGraphType>, System.Func<System.Type, GraphQL.Types.IGraphType>, GraphQL.Conversion.INameConverter, bool) in GraphTypesLookup.cs
    GraphQL.Types.Schema.CreateTypesLookup() in Schema.cs
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
```

Adding `UserType` and `TaskType` to DI container solves this error.

Now, your original problem: you should use `IDocumentWriter` to write the response, you can't just serialize `executionResult` by returning `Ok(executionResult)`.
Use this code to write response (stolen from official [graphql-dotnet/examples](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/examples/blob/master/src/AspNetCoreCustom/Example/GraphQLMiddleware.cs#L75) repo):

```
private async Task WriteResponseAsync(HttpContext context, ExecutionResult result)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.StatusCode = result.Errors?.Any() == true ? (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest : (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;

    await _documentWriter.WriteAsync(context.Response.Body, result);
}
```

The updated `GraphQLController.cs`

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public sealed class GraphQLController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISchema _schema;
    private readonly IDocumentExecuter _documentExecuter;
    private readonly IDocumentWriter _documentWriter;

    public GraphQLController(ISchema schema, IDocumentExecuter documentExecuter, IDocumentWriter documentWriter)
    {
        _schema = schema;
        _documentExecuter = documentExecuter;
        _documentWriter = documentWriter;
    }

    public async Task Post([FromBody] GraphQLRequest graphQlRequest)
    {
        ExecutionOptions executionOptions = new ExecutionOptions()
        {
            Schema = _schema,
            Query = graphQlRequest.Query,
            Inputs = graphQlRequest.Variables?.ToInputs()
        };

        ExecutionResult executionResult = await _documentExecuter.ExecuteAsync(executionOptions);

        await WriteResponseAsync(HttpContext, executionResult);
    }

    private async Task WriteResponseAsync(HttpContext context, ExecutionResult result)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = result.Errors?.Any() == true ? (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest : (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
    
        await _documentWriter.WriteAsync(context.Response.Body, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: And I'd recommend to use middleware as much simpler and cleaner way to use library. See this example: https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/examples/tree/master/src/AspNetCore

Comment: yes, the error is gone! But GraphiQL is not able to load a schema .. how can I add it?

Comment: Emm, I actually can see the schema in Docs after registering missing types and writing the response to with `IDocumentWriter`. I'll update the answer with Controller code

Answer (score 0):

It's a classic for Json resolvers. if you have navigation properties or properties that reference eachother.

Often this can be fixed by either returning a mapped result, or by adjusting the Json Serializer settings.

I'm unsure whether this is fixed in .Net Core 3.1
but you can to the startup.cs add

install `Newtonsoft Json`if you haven't already.

```
services
  .AddControllers()
  .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
  {
      options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
  });
```

hope this resolves it.

here's some article about the issue.

https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/03/15/fixing-json-self-referencing-loop-exceptions/

[.net core 3 not having ReferenceLoopHandling in AddJsonOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58006152/net-core-3-not-having-referenceloophandling-in-addjsonoptions)

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm not using Newtonsoft. Since Microsoft provides it's own JSON lib now I installed the `GraphQL.SystemTextJson` package as described in the docs here https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet#installation

Comment: it's been a known issue before that system.text.json wasn't mature enough because of referenceloop handling error. 
Strongly recommend that you either update to .net core 5 then or swap out system.text.json with newtonsofts. :)
btw: here's a link of microsofts own documentation their json serializer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1 
which even in 3.1 still doesnt appear to be supporting the referenceloop error

Comment: hmm I migrated to .NET 5 but unfortunately still get an error .. (updated my question) I understand your reasons to use Newtonsoft but I would like to avoid external packages as a workaround .... :S

Comment: So it's no longer the referenceloop handling error. hurray! 
unfortunately now you've run into another unsupported feature in the system.text.json  
take a look at this registered issue for instance stating the same fact that system.text.json throws this exception.
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/41920
Still my strongest recommendation would be to just switch to newtonsoft which have been around for ages and does the work.

Comment: hmm :/ thanks. But I think my code is wrong because other people use this package too or at least someone tried it before releasing it?