# Where is IOptions<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions> registered in ASP.NET Core 7?

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net

A while ago I switched from using `.AddNewtonsoftJson()` in my .NET Core 7 app to using `.AddJsonOptions()`.

I came across an issue with nswag (circular reference) and needed to change the settings used by [`OpenApiGeneratorCommandBase`](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/blob/master/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Generation/OpenApiGeneratorCommandBase.cs). That class uses `MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions` for serialization.

Since I don't use `AddNewtonsoftJson` anymore I would maybe have expected that `IOptions<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>` wouldn't have been defined - but it is and I can't find where.

```
// this has a value but I don't know why
var mvcJsonOptions = serviceProvider?.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>>();
```

I've looked all through the Microsoft source code. `MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions` is defined [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/src/MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions.cs) but I can't find a registration for `IOptions<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>`.

Where is this getting defined?

Comment: It isn't: `IOptions<T>` is [registered as an open generic](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/src/OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L26), which resolves with a default instance of `T`, [created using `Activator.CreateInstance`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/src/OptionsFactory.cs#L102).